# How to change appearance of a symbol with CSS ? For eg. In my calculator i used operator(+,-,/,%,*) but the multiple (*) looks bad

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to change the looks of operator * as its looking bad in calculator and when i used x js give error(VM24:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
at HTMLButtonElement. (script.js:7:21)) probably because i used (eval()).
Make operator into symbol without this error.
Also when the calculator display is empty (no number) and if we hit (+,-,/,%,*) they are displayed do something that they won't get displayed in empty display.
Also when empty screen if we hit (=) it showed undefined in display screen. Why it's happing ?
and help me resolve it that it won't display undefined.

```js
let string = "";
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.keys');

Array.from(buttons).forEach((keys) => {
  keys.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    if (e.target.innerHTML == '=') {
      string = eval(string);
      document.querySelector('input').value = string;
    }
    else if (e.target.innerHTML == 'C') {
      string = ""
      document.querySelector('input').value = string;
    }
    else if (e.target.innerHTML == 'backspace') {
      string = document.querySelector('input').value
      document.querySelector('input').value = string.substring(0, string.length - 1);
string = ""
    }
   
    else {
      console.log(e.target)
      string = string + e.target.innerHTML;
      document.querySelector('input').value = string;
    }
  })
})


// var value = document.getElementById("d").value;
// document.getElementById("d").value = value.substr(0, value.length - 1);
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    background-color: blanchedalmond;
}

.bcg {
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 35px;
    background-color: black;
    height: 100%;
    width: 312px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 2px solid orange;


}

.calcu-cont {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

h1 {
    color: orangered;
    margin-bottom: 75px;
}

.disp {
    margin: 8px 0px -7.6px 0px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}

.row {
    margin: 8px 0px;
}


.display-row {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    border: none;
    width: 291px;
    font-size: 35px;
    padding: 10px;
    color: white;
    outline: none;
    background-color: black;
    text-align: right;
}


.keys {
    width: 75px;
    padding: 25px;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;

}


.orange-key {
    color: orangered;
}

.orange-key-bcg-round {
    background-color: orangered;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 100%;
    font-weight: 300;
}

.material-symbols-outlined {
    font-size: 14px;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <!-- google icon -->
    <link rel="stylesheet"
        href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@20..48,100..700,0..1,-50..200" />

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- My files -->
    <!-- css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>

<body>

    <!-- backbone-body -->
    <div class="bcg">

        <!-- calcu-container -->
        <div class="calcu-cont">


            <h1>Calculator</h1>

            <!-- display -->
            <div class="disp">
                <input type="text" class="display-row" maxlength="26" readonly>
            </div>

            <!-- keys-Divided into rows  -->
            <div class="row">
                <button class="button keys orange-key nob">C</button>
                <button class="button keys orange-key nob material-icons">backspace</button>
                <button class="button keys orange-key nob">%</button>
                <button class="button keys orange-key nob">/</button>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <button class="button keys">7</button>
                <button class="button keys">8</button>
                <button class="button keys">9</button>
                <button class="button keys orange-key ">*</button>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <button class="button keys">4</button>
                <button class="button keys">5</button>
                <button class="button keys">6</button>
                <button class="button keys orange-key">-</button>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <button class="button keys">1</button>
                <button class="button keys">2</button>
                <button class="button keys">3</button>
                <button class="button keys orange-key">+</button>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <button class="button keys orange-key"><span class="material-symbols-outlined">
                        calculate
                    </span></button>
                <button class="button keys">0</button>
                <button class="button keys">.</button>
                <button class="button keys orange-key-bcg-round">=</button>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- JS -->
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Change the font?

Comment: Using "x" instead of "*" will not cause an error. What **exactly** did you try?

Comment: @Pointy I did that but it gave me error i replace * with x but it won't worked

Comment: @PunitSoni again, **what exactly was the error**

Comment: @t.niese ah. Well, that's probably not the best thing to do :)

Answer (score 1):

`eval()` works against strings that contain valid javascript.

`eval('2+2')` will return 4, because + is the addition operator.
`eval('2*2')` will return 4, because * is the multiplication operator.
`eval('2x2')` will return an error, because x is a letter. "2x2" is not valid javascript.

If you want to display `•` or `x` or something else on the button, translate that character back to the actual operator before calling `eval` on it:

```
    ...} else if (e.target.innerHTML === 'x') {
      string = string + '*';
      document.querySelector('input').value = string;
    } else {...
```

(I'll spare you the usual safety lecture about why you shouldn't be using eval.)

Answer (score 0):

Replace `*` with `×` in the HTML and do
`string = string.replace('×', '*')`
before running
`eval(string);`

**Update:** It's now working with fontawesome divider, but you don't *need* to use that. You can directly use this character `÷` and then replace by `/`, like we did for `×`. I recommend that approach instead.

```js
let string = "";
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.keys');

Array.from(buttons).forEach((keys) => {
  keys.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    if (e.target.innerHTML == '=') {
      string = string.replace('×', '*') // <--- add this
      string = eval(string);
      document.querySelector('input').value = string;
    }
    else if (e.target.innerHTML == 'C') {
      string = ""
      document.querySelector('input').value = string;
    }
    else if (e.target.innerHTML == 'backspace') {
      string = document.querySelector('input').value
      document.querySelector('input').value = string.substring(0, string.length - 1);
string = ""
    }
    else {
      console.log(e.target)
      string = string + `${e.target.dataset.operator || e.target.innerHTML}`;
      document.querySelector('input').value = string;
    }
  })
})


// var value = document.getElementById("d").value;
// document.getElementById("d").value = value.substr(0, value.length - 1);
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    background-color: blanchedalmond;
}

.bcg {
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 35px;
    background-color: black;
    height: 100%;
    width: 312px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 2px solid orange;


}

.calcu-cont {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

h1 {
    color: orangered;
    margin-bottom: 75px;
}

.disp {
    margin: 8px 0px -7.6px 0px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}

.row {
    margin: 8px 0px;
}


.display-row {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    border: none;
    width: 291px;
    font-size: 35px;
    padding: 10px;
    color: white;
    outline: none;
    background-color: black;
    text-align: right;
}

.keys {
    width: 75px;
    padding: 25px;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;

}

.orange-key {
    color: orangered;
}

.orange-key-bcg-round {
    background-color: orangered;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 100%;
    font-weight: 300;
}

.material-symbols-outlined {
    font-size: 14px;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <!-- google icon -->
    <link rel="stylesheet"
        href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@20..48,100..700,0..1,-50..200" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.2/css/all.min.css>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- My files -->
    <!-- css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>

<body>

    <!-- backbone-body -->
    <div class="bcg">

        <!-- calcu-container -->
        <div class="calcu-cont">


            <h1>Calculator</h1>

            <!-- display -->
            <div class="disp">
                <input type="text" class="display-row" maxlength="26" readonly>
            </div>

            <!-- keys-Divided into rows  -->
            <div class="row">
                <button class="button keys orange-key nob">C</button>
                <button class="button keys orange-key nob material-icons">backspace</button>
                <button class="button keys orange-key nob">%</button>
                <button class="button keys orange-key nob" data-operator="/">
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-divide"></i>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <button class="button keys">7</button>
                <button class="button keys">8</button>
                <button class="button keys">9</button>
                <button class="button keys orange-key">×</button>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <button class="button keys">4</button>
                <button class="button keys">5</button>
                <button class="button keys">6</button>
                <button class="button keys orange-key">-</button>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <button class="button keys">1</button>
                <button class="button keys">2</button>
                <button class="button keys">3</button>
                <button class="button keys orange-key">+</button>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <button class="button keys orange-key"><span class="material-symbols-outlined">
                        calculate
                    </span></button>
                <button class="button keys">0</button>
                <button class="button keys">.</button>
                <button class="button keys orange-key-bcg-round">=</button>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- JS -->
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: it can replace character  what about symbols For ex. if I put font awesome  symbol of divide then how can I replace it with this / in js as <I> </I>  didn't  contain anything  hope u understand what I'm saying

Comment: I understood don't worry. Check the updated answer.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend changing the symbol to "x". 
You could also switch the / character to ÷. 
Another option entirely is to change the font.